# Reference is not fully initialized

Tags: scala, chisel

I have a module like below:

```
class ComputationIO[T <: Data](val OperandType: T) extends Bundle {
    val data = OperandType.cloneType
}

class Computation [T <: Data] (OperandType: T) extends Module {
    val io = IO( new Bundle {
        val in = Input(new ComputationIO(OperandType))
    })
    // REST OF THE CODE HERE...
}
```

And, I'm instantiating the `Computation` like below:

```
    val compUnit  = for (i <- 0 until nParal) yield {
        val Comp =  Module(new Computation(UInt(32.W)))
        Comp
    }
```

However, although I'm passing `UInt(32.W)` to the constructor, it gives me the following **error**:

```
firrtl.passes.CheckInitialization$RefNotInitializedException:Reference compUnit is not fully initialized.                                                                                                                                                           
[error]    : compUnit.io.in.OperandType <= VOID
```

I can solve the problem by removing the `val` in the IO class and overriding the `cloneType`, sth like below:

```
class ComputationIO[T <: Data](OperandType: T) extends Bundle {
    val data = OperandType.cloneType

    override def cloneType = new ComputationIO(OperandType).asInstanceOf[this.type ]
}
```

But, I was wondering what is the problem of the first approach? The constructor has been initialized. So, the `not fully initialized` error doesn't make sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.chisel-lang.org/chisel3/docs/explanations/bundles-and-vecs.html#a-note-on-clonetype) linked in the other answer mentions this but I want to highlight a piece:

> The only caveat is if you are passing something of type Data as a “generator” parameter, in which case you should make it a private val.

This is due to the fact that if you make a class parameter a `val`, it becomes a public field of the class. The hardware fields of a `Bundle` are defined to be "the public fields of the class of type `Data`". Thus, `val OperandType` is a field of the class, it would be the same as writing:

```scala
class ComputationIO[T <: Data](_operandType: T) extends Bundle {
    val OperandType = _operandType
    val data = OperandType.cloneType
}
```

In fact, you only need to call `cloneType` on `OperandType` because you get field aliasing with `OperandType` and `data` being the exact same object.
This is obviously only an issue because you unintentionally have `OperandType` as a public field of the Bundle.

You can deal with this by making it a `private val` which will not cause it to become a field of the `Bundle`:

```scala
class ComputationIO[T <: Data](private val OperandType: T) extends Bundle {
    val data = OperandType // note .cloneType not necessary
}
```

Note that beginning in Chisel v3.4.3, there is opt-in Autoclonetype2 which does not require parameters to be vals to be able to infer clonetype, you can see the [release notes](https://github.com/chipsalliance/chisel3/releases/tag/v3.4.3) for more information. Autoclonetype2 will become the default in Chisel v3.5.0 (not yet released).